# Longest common substring modified

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was reading through Longest Common substring between two strings using suffix arrays.I coded program to develop a suffix array of string in O(N) complexity.

Now I want to modify the program to find ALL the longest common substrings of two strings.How to do it.

Example : 
`Let S1=xyzabc S2=abcxyz then here answer is length of Longest common sub string is 3 and {"abc","xyz"}`

Please Help
(Assume that I had found suffix array in array SA[])

```
void kasaiLCP () {
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) c [SA [i]] = i;
LCP [0] = 0;
for (int i = 0, h = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) if (c[i] > 0) {
        int j = SA [c [i] - 1];
        while (i + h < str.length() && j + h < str.length() && str [i + h] == str [j + h]) ++h;
        LCP [c [i]] = h;
        if (h > 0) --h;
    }
}
```

Is this LCP implementation correct ? My suffix array is 0-indexed.

For S1=abcabc and S2=bc.
My suffix array SA[]=[6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2]

And LCP array be=[0,0,3,0,2,2,0,1,1]

Is it correct ?

Comment: Create a generalized suffix array of `S1$S2`. Set up a height array with RMQ to find the LCP of suffixes in O(1). Mark every suffix with the number of the string it came from. Pass through the SA, computing the LCA of every suffix with the most recently seen suffix from the other string. you will have all inclusion-maximal common substrings. Find the longest of those. If you can implement an algorithm that constructs the suffix array in linear time, this should be a piece of cake :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Please explain "Set up a height array with RMQ to find the LCP of suffixes in O(1)".Please elaborate what you are trying to say.Am not getting you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array

Comment: @NiklasB. I had gone through this.But it didnt helped alot

Comment: Actually you don't need that. You just need the LCP of adjacent suffixes in the SA

Comment: @NiklasB. Given an suffix array SA (0-based indexed) how to compute LCP.?

Comment: There are multiple references on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array#Efficient_Construction_Algorithms)

Comment: Now what I don't understand, you would need LCP queries just as well for the "normal" longest common substring problem. I thought you know how to solve that one?

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/computing-the-longest-common-substring-of-two-strings-using-suffix-arrays

Comment: as a side node for the downvoter. The way the question is framed is decent enough for a first post.

Comment: Check this link [**Analysis of Longest common substring matching**](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2014/10/analysis-of-longest-common-substring_18.html)